# Populating Html Helpers route arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there a way to populate anonymous type properties (route arguments) in Html Helpers like Html.ActionLink or Url.Action with data.

Example.

Create link like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { propertyName = propertyValue })">Anchor Text</a>
```

... and populate propertyValue with data extracted from current state of DOM (using Javascript).

I know there's a lot of ways that I can get that logic to work (ex. using form data and passing it to controller) but I'm just curious if a provided scenario is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> populate propertyValue with data extracted from current state of DOM (using Javascript)

No.

C# runs on the server, JavaScript runs on the client.  You can't use JavaScript on the client to modify code which *already ran* on the server.  You *can* use JavaScript to modify the markup which gets *emitted* to the client, and the first step in that would be to examine what that markup actually is.  (In this case it looks like you'd be modifying a URL, which may involve some interesting string parsing in the JavaScript code.)

But no, JavaScript can't affect your calls to HTML Helpers.